# Setting up linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

Setup a linear system and solve to get the equation of a plane that contains points $x = (4,0, −2)$, $y = (2,3, -1)$ and $z = (0,0,1)$.
How do we set up an equation like do we use transformation matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General equation of a plane is $$ax+by+cz=d$$
Plug the coordinates and get the system
$$\begin{cases}
4 a-2 c=d\\
2 a+3 b-c=d\\
c=d\\
\end{cases}
$$
solutions are
$a= \frac{3 d}{4},b= \frac{d}{6},c= d$

So the equation of the plane is
$$\frac{3 }{4}d x+\frac{d}{6}y+dz=d$$
simplify and rearrange
$$9 x+2 y+12 z=12$$